# OpenTelemetry: trying to instrument Akka with the Java agent

Tags: akka, open-telemetry

I'm trying to put together a minimal example of extracting metrics/traces from Akka using the OpenTelemetry Java agent, before moving to one of the actual applications in our company.
So I downloaded the [Akka Actors Quickstart with Scala](https://developer.lightbend.com/guides/akka-quickstart-scala/?_ga=2.80936415.953939373.1646908200-1390930993.1646908200) sample application and ran it with

```
-javaagent:/path/opentelemetry-javaagent.jar
-Dotel.metrics.exporter=otlp
-Dotel.traces.exporter=otlp
```

so that it would send metrics & traces to my local OTel Collector instance.
The thing starts without errors and I can see a message from the agent at the beginning of the log, but the only metrics or traces that I see in the Collector are JVM ones.

Am I doing something wrong? Usage instructions for the agent are quite simple, so I'm confused about what is missing...

Comment: What metrics would you expect to get out of the box that weren't generic JVM ones?  (Disclaimer: I'm employed by Lightbend, which offers a telemetry implementation that is customized for Akka)

Comment: [This](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation#supported-libraries-frameworks-and-application-servers) promises support for Akka and may other libraries out of the box, so I was expecting  some actor-related metrics.

Comment: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/discussions/4909 indicates that the support for metrics is limited to Akka HTTP, with no metrics for other parts of Akka.

Comment: As someone that doesn't work for Lightbend, let me back up Levi's recommendation to look at Akka Insights from Lightbend instead. That's the exact use case it's designed for, and it's going to be a lot easier to config and have a lot less runtime performance impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levi's comment gave me the answer by pointing at https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/discussions/4909.
At the moment the OT agent has no support for Akka actors.